# Publish news feed through cron job

Tags: php, facebook, feed

It is possible to publish news feed on user's wall through a cron job, if yes then how, what does facebook offer to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do it if you have the oauth token for the user using the new graph api:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/status

See the 'publishing to facebook' section here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api which demonstrates how to use `curl` to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Via cron job is possible, but you will need the offline_access extended permission which gives longer lived session keys.

These can be used to update the user's profile even when they are not online.

Answer (score 0):

Via `cron job` - no. Cron is server side tool.
You can do it with JavaScript's `setTimeout()` function.